# How to check if program is installed with Qt in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to check if Matlab is installed on the user's computer using Qt in C++. Is this possible? I read some things about QProcess but no one seems to be sure about it and if it a cross platform solution.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I bet solution is platform dependent. On Linux I would check if file is available in $PATH.

Comment: I am only interested in doing the check on Windows and Mac. So, what you're telling me is that there is no crossplatorm way and i guess I should put an #ifdef and check seperately both cases. Can you point out the Win and Mac solution?

Comment: For OS X, I suggest you research [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar problem with other software here is sample:

```
QString qstr_ext = ".ext_data";
LPCWSTR wstr_ext = (const wchar_t*)qstr_ext.utf16();

// Create and reset buffer
TCHAR buff[1024];
DWORD size = sizeof(buff);
memset(&buff, '\0', sizeof(buff));

// Read application path for extension
HRESULT err = AssocQueryString(ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, wstr_ext, NULL, buff, &size);

if(S_OK == err)
{
    // Convert to wstring
    std::wstring wstring_data(&buff[0]);
    // To QString
    QString appPath = QString::fromStdWString(wstring_data);

    qDebug() << appPath;
}
```

What that is doing is get 'file extension' from registry (for Matlab [file extensions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/mathworks-file-extensions.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)), then using Windows API read where matlab is installed.

To use this in cross-platform, will be more complicated, as on Windows you can read registry, on OSX for example you can use 'find' command line to figure out where is (if exist then command will return location)

Similar way can be done on Linux - using 'find' command.

So QProcess is a way to do, but is quite slow on *nix platforms as there no 'registry' where application is installed or not (AFIK there no registry, you can use apt-get in debian for example to find is installed or not, but is not cross-linux solution)

Comment: I'm using in my current project, and working fine (Qt 5.5.1/Win7)


Edit: LIBS += -lShlwapi (in *.pro) and '#include <Shlwapi.h>'

Comment: so to use this to check for matlab, what do i have to change? Can you also list the #includes?

Comment: ".ext_data" to any file format that you know will be used in system, like for application is .exe, then for your matlab will be any other.

Comment: but what if the user has not produced any matlab files ?

Comment: This don't matter, as my solution read registry for 'application' not for user.
Each file extension can be registered to run with 'Application'.
For example .cpp file will be opened with Visual studio, and .txt file will be opened with Notepad ... and all other extensions are opened with assigned application.  
If file extension is not assigned to any app, Windows will display 'Open with' window, and code will return 'empty string' - as there no 'default' app for this extension.

Comment: I am inlucding the Shlwapi header but I'm getting a link error at the AssocQueryString function